# Shiny and GoogleVis in Popup window

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis, googlevis

I'm new to Shiny and R in general and could do with some help!

I've been trying to get some googleVis outputs into Shiny without success. I can get gvis outputs for bubble, motion and scatter charts directly in R but not in a shiny app.

I've checked reference code from Mages and others but I don't get an output chart in Shiny.

I've stripped it back to its most basic but can't get the visualisation. Is there anyone who could give me a pointer on what I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

```
#UI.R
library(shiny)
library(googleVis)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("GoogleVis example"),
  sidebarLayout(
           sidebarPanel(
               h4("GoogleVis and Shiny")

               ),
       mainPanel(
            htmlOutput("bubble")

          )
      ))
  )


#Server.R
library(shiny)
library(googleVis)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
  Newyork=read.csv("data/Newyork.csv")
    output$bubble<- renderGvis({

      gvisBubbleChart(Newyork, idvar="County", xvar="Population", yvar="Crime.Rate") 

    })
})
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code except that it's not reproducible. We don't have access to `Newyork.csv`. Try using 'builtin' data like `mtcars`.

Comment: I've solved my own prooblem! thanks to another post from a long time ago. It seems that Shiny has an issue with rendering googlevis charts in the pop up window, clicking open in browser solves the problem....

Comment: The free Rstudio preview browser does not do SSL, and `googlevis` needs SSL.